# ¿Cual es el significado de "mesmerismo"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, significado

Estaba leyendo un artículo sobre los beneficios de despertar temprano y me crucé con esta frase.

> Sigo esta rutina todos los días sin variación. La repetición misma se convierte en lo importante; es una forma de mesmerismo. Me hipnotizo para alcanzar un estado mental más profundo.

¿Para ustedes qué es **mesmerismo**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pues yo apostaba porque fuese una burda adaptación del inglés [*mesmerize*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mesmerize) como sinónimo de hipnotizar pero, para mi sorpresa, la palabra "mesmerismo" está tal cual recogida en el diccionario y con el mismo significado que en inglés:

> [**mesmerismo**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=P2uRTRv)
>   1. m. Doctrina del magnetismo animal, expuesta en la segunda mitad del siglo XVIII por el médico alemán Mesmer.

Básicamente el mesmerismo es (o, quizá más bien, era) una especie de técnica de hipnosis que buscaba la sanación, no el control del sujeto.

En inglés se usa con relativa frecuencia *"mesmerizing"* para referirse a cosas que te dejan como embobado, hipnotizado.

En el texto que planteas, entiendo que el autor lo usa en sentido más o menos literal, sobre todo teniendo en cuenta que inmediatamente después refuerza dicho sentido cuando dice que "se hipnotiza"; nos quiere decir que entiende esa repetición de la rutina como una forma de hipnosis beneficiosa para su salud.

Comment: Era la respuesta que buscaba, saludos.

Comment: Gracias por responder.